# Android Studio - Java: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT results in invalid Uri

Tags: java, android, uri

I want to open a .csv file to import the data to a local database on the phone. I also what to let the user choose the .csv file using the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent, however when I look at the resulting Uri and try `uri.getPath()` it returns `/document/85`.

I'm expecting something more like `/downloads/file.csv` but it doesn't even contain the filename.

I have only tested this on a phone running android 11, so it may be a permissions problem, but I have already granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

After I check for permissions, it just does 3 steps:

```
public void Import(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/csv");

    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_BACKUP);
}
```

then it handles the result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    if (requestCode == OPEN_BACKUP && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            ImportCSV(this, uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it calls this function:

```
private void ImportCSV(Context ctx, Uri uri){
    try {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(uri.getPath()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Bruh", uri.getPath());     //Always logs '/document/85'
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm almost certain the problem is with the 2nd step, but I have no idea what could be the issue.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

(Just ask if you need any more info)

Comment: Uri.getPath() does not give you a file system path. Uri.toSting() is the content scheme for the file. Open an inputstream for the uri then read from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

For FileReader you can use FileDescriptor from Uri. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file

```
FileReader(contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r").fileDescriptor)
```